# Ignoring apostrophe while capturing contents in single quotes REGEX

Tags: php, regex, pcre

The issue for me here is to capture the content inside single quotes(like 'xyz').
But the apostrophe which is the same symbol as a single quote(') is coming in the way!

The regex I've written is : `/(\w\'\w)(*SKIP)(*F)|(\'[^\']*\')/`

The example i have used is  : `Hello ma'am 'This is Prashanth's book.'`

What needs to be captured is : `'This is Prashanth's book.'`.

But, what's capured is : `'This is Prashanth'`!

Here is the link of what i tried on [online regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/de49Ro/1)

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `[^\']` to capture a text that contains `'` with in and in your example, `This is Prashanth's book.` contains a `'` character within the text. You need to modify your regex to use `.*?` instead of `[^\']` and can write your regex as this,

```
(\w'\w)(*SKIP)(*F)|('.*?'\B)
```

**[Demo with your updated regex](https://regex101.com/r/de49Ro/2)**

Also, you don't need to escape a single quote `'` as that has no special meaning in regex.

From your example, it is not clear whether you want the captured match to contain `'` around the match or not. In case you don't want `'` to be captured in the match, you can use a lookarounds based regex and use this,

```
(?<=\B').*?(?='\B)
```

**Explanation of regex:**

- `(?<=\B')` - This positive look behind ensures what gets captured in match is preceded by a single quote which is not preceded by a word character which is ensured by `\B`
- `.*?` - Captures the text in non-greedy manner
- `(?='\B)` - Ensures the matched text is followed by a single quote and `\B` ensures it doesn't match a quote that is immediately followed by any word character. E.g. it won't match an ending quote like `'s`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pEz8ZC/1)**

Comment: Pleased to help :)

Comment: did you downvote the question? Someone did! I dont undestand why! :(

Comment: @PrashanthBenny: No I didn't downvote. Why would I answer a question if I downvoted. Also, getting downvotes on questions in regex tag is a normal trend. Anyway, take my upvote as your question is good and you showed what you tried with samples.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your support Pushpesh. This just saved my day from being screwed up with this issue... I had not actually looked at \B as a possibility at all :D

Answer (score 1):

For the string you have provided, you can use the regex:

```
\B'\K(?:(?!'\B).)+
```

[**Click for Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/g8Fv8f/2)

**Explanation:**

- `\B` - a non-word boundary
- `'` - matches a `'`
- `\K` - forget everything matched so far
- `(?:(?!'\B).)+` - matches 1+ occurrences of any character(except newline) which does not start with `'` followed by a non-word boundary

Comment: Wow, `\K`. Didn't know about it for years... Thanks!